# Run an installer inside my program

Tags: javascript, operating-system

How can I run an installer of an independent program (exe file) from inside of my code?
The idea in general is program which install other programs. 
Thanks!
Barak

Comment: I don't get how this question deserves the [tag:javascript] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use exec of node.js

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('path/to/exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```